# JavaScript that highlights current day in "hours of operation" part of website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of the days and hours of operation of a business:

```
{% load static %}

<link type = "text/javascript" href="{% static 'core/js/index.js' %}">

         <div class = "col-md-4">
             <div class = "business-hours">
                <h2 class="title">Opening Hours</h2>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled opening-hours">
                        <li>Sunday <span class="pull-right">Closed</span></li>
                        <li>Monday <span class="pull-right">9:00-22:00</span></li>
                        <li>Tuesday <span class="pull-right">9:00-22:00</span></li>
                        <li>Wednesday <span class="pull-right">9:00-22:00</span></li>
                        <li>Thursday <span class="pull-right">9:00-22:00</span></li>
                        <li>Friday <span class="pull-right">9:00-23:30</span></li>
                        <li>Saturday <span class="pull-right">14:00-23:30</span></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
```

And am trying to use JavaScript so that the current day is highlighted when a user visits the website:

```
// highlight current day on opeining hours
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.opening-hours li').eq(new Date().getDay()).addClass('today');
});
```

The above JavaScript is not producing any results and I am not sure why. Note: this is in a Django project with app `core`, and the JS file is located at `core/static/core/js/index.js`.

**EDIT:**

This is the error message shown in the console:

> error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: I think youre missing the child selector: *.opening-hours > li*

Comment: do you get any error message in the console?

Comment: @Jonasw It should work either way, right, as a descendant selector? (at least that's what the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) say)

Comment: @freginold I opened the console and see "error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"

Comment: @JustinO'Brien If you're using Bootstrap, you have to load jQuery *before* you load the Bootstrap files. That could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that either jQuery wasn't loaded, or it wasn't loaded before Bootstrap's JavaScript.  You will need to load jQuery *before* loading the Bootstrap JavaScript file.  Your `script` tags should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```